# How to remove door hinge cap

Tags: doors

Realised that door started to squeaking and the sound is coming from the hinge. The pin cap is slightly bigger than the hinge. Found a video on YouTube that suggested to try with a vice wrench and tap it with hammer but no result. I started to wonder if the pin is removable or not. Any suggestions?

[image: Hinge picture]

Comment: Vice wrench can damage finish, would try a flat blade screwdriver and hammer.  Bottom piece should be the cap, top piece should be top of pin.

Comment: Look at the bottom. I've seen a few that screw on.

Comment: You might just try spraying a bit of lube into the hinge without trying to disassemble it. Something like a PTFE or white lithium spray (not WD-40 - it's not really a lubricant, though it will lubricate for a short period of time).

Comment: That hinge looks like it's permanently lubricated.

Comment: check the bottom cap ... there may be a hole in it for inserting a metal rod for punching out the hinge pin